# Scp from one server to another server?

Tags: scp

I am trying to copy files from one server directly to another, bypassing my local computer.

I did

```
scp -r usrname@server1.com:~/data/* usrname@server2.com:~/data/
Password: 
Host key verification failed.
lost connection
```

Is this even possible? How may I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the output of following command- scp -r -v usrname@server1.com:~/data/* usrname@server2.com:~/data/

Answer (score 84):

Something I use fairly often when there is no connection possible between the two servers

```
scp -3 user@server1:/path/to/file user@server2:/path/to/file
```

source

> -3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly
>   between the two
>                remote hosts.  Note that this option disables the progress meter.

Assuming youu have a good connection to both, its not too slow.

Comment: In addition if you need to use special ports on both servers: http://superuser.com/questions/686394/scp-between-two-remote-hosts-from-my-third-pc

Comment: Don't forget to add the `-r` flag if you're copying a directory.

Answer (score 20):

Yes this is possible, but only if `server1.com` can reach `server2.com` by using that name. If not you will probably get a message: `ssh: connect to host server2 port 22: Connection refused`

The `man` page for `scp` clearly states that it copies between hosts on a network and that:

> Copies between two remote hosts are also permitted.

What you should do (once) is `ssh` to `username@server1.com` and from there `ssh` to `username@server2.com`. Answer the authenticity question you'll get with yes, to get rid of the host key verification message while doing the `scp`

You might have to enable the forwarding agent with:

```
scp -o "ForwardAgent yes" -r usrname@server1.com:~/data/* usrname@server2.com:~/data/
```

But make sure you realise the danger in that (`man ssh_config`)

Comment: I just `ssh`ed from `server1.com` to `server2.com`, and I indeed answered the question and succeeded. Then, I go back to my local computer, do it again, and get the `server2.com`'s password prompt. But it fails there with:`Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).
lost connection`

Comment: @SibbsGambling I think this relies on forwarding your private key. Can you login to both servers without providing a password? Could you login from `server1` to `server2` without providing a password. You might have to set "ForwardAgent yes".

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to check i you are able to ssh to server2 without any error, if you get the same error, then please open the file `~/.ssh/known_hosts` and search the server2 key and delete it.

Then check if you are able to ping the server by the host name

If not then please edit both the server host file as mentioned below

```
 #vi /etc/hosts  
 server1 192.186.x.x  
 server2 192.186.x.xx   
 :wq   ---> to save
```

After you are done with this cd to the location of the file which you want to copy to the server2

the `scp file_name user@server2:/path_to_the_directory`   ---> you can use the IP instead of the hostname you can mention `-R` to copy a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check if `~/.ssh/known_hosts` have proper records for both servers

Check also if server1 have proper `~/.ssh/known_hosts` record for server2

Answer (score 0):

For Linux ,Use the following command to seamlessly copy file/folder from one server to another. This also ensures that the job is completed even if you are disconnected in between from the servers.

```
nohup bash -c 'scp -r [user_source@Soure_Server_ip]:/[path_to_folder] [user_dest@destination_server_ip]:/[path_to_destination_folder]'>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create a configuration file in `~/.ssh/config` and write into it something like:

```
Host src_host
    HostName example.com
    User user1
    Port 22
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile /path/to/secret-key

Host dest_host
    HostName 99.111.22.333
    User user2
    Port 3333
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile /path/to/secret-key2
```

Then, you can check whether the configuration file is working with `ssh -F ~/.ssh/config src_host`, where `-F` allows you to specify a non-default path to a configuration file. I had to go through this process, since `ssh` was ignoring `~/.ssh/config`.

Finally, you can `scp` between the two hosts:

```
scp -3v -F .ssh/config src-host:/path/to/file1 dest-host:/path/to/file2
```

- `-3` directs the traffic through your machine
- `-v` produces a verbose output

Answer (score -2):

You can use this below command to copy file from one server to other:

```
scp source_user@source_remote_host:/usr/bin/mysql_backup.sh \
         target_user@target_remote_host:/var/tmp/
```